# airline in conemu - changing colors on page scroll

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-airline

I have finally got vim with airline plugin to work on windows with conemu thanks to [this topic](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues/513)

Almost everything is good right now except some problems with colors in airline when screen is scrolled. Check below gif:
[image]

I'm looking forward to find the culprit.

At the beginning result was worse, but I commented everything that was reduntant. In spare time I will check each and every single setting in the vimrc file. But still can't get the airline to hold its colors.

You can find my vimrc [here](https://gist.github.com/lkurylo/aa947a1ae6d7185aa064)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been fixed in ConEmu 151025